How can I store the text between \begin{env} and \end{env} as a token list?
I can store the text as a token sequence: if "create" new toks as \newtoks\mytoks and define a command \def\mycommand#1{\mytoks={#1}} I can write
\mycommand{Some text}
and obtain non-empty toks \mytoks containing the string "Some text".
But I would like to do the same using use the \begin/\end construction of the type
\begin{myenv}
Some text.
\end{myenv}
to store this "Some text." in \mytoks.
How should I define the new environment myenv?

Why exactly as a token list?

Do you know \NewDocumentEnvironment? If not, see section 2.5 till 2.11 of the new version of usrguide.pdf. If, see section 2.11 of the new version of usrguide.pdf.

This token list wiil be used later in our style file. Using \toks is convenient.

IMHO it would help us help you, if you would add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem and your use case. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

That's easy enough:
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenv}{+b}{%
  \global\mytoks={#1}%
}{}


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
